# Stemming and Lemmatization in Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have used Stanford NLP Library to perform stemming and lemmatization on a sentence. 
For example, Car is an easy way for commute. But there are too many cars on roads these days.

So the expected output is:

```
car be easy way commute car road day
```

But I am getting this :

```
ArrayBuffer(car, easy, way, for, commute, but, there, too, many, car, road, these, day)
```

Here is the code

```
val stopWords = sc.broadcast(
  scala.io.Source.fromFile("src/main/common-english-words.txt").getLines().toSet).value

def plainTextToLemmas(text: String, stopWords: Set[String]): Seq[String] = {
  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma")
  val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
  val doc = new Annotation(text)
  pipeline.annotate(doc)
  val lemmas = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
  val sentences = doc.get(classOf[SentencesAnnotation])
  for (sentence <- sentences; token <- sentence.get(classOf[TokensAnnotation])) {
    val lemma = token.get(classOf[LemmaAnnotation])
    if (lemma.length > 2 && !stopWords.contains(lemma)) {
      lemmas += lemma.toLowerCase
    }
  }
  lemmas
}
val lemmatized = stringRDD.map(plainTextToLemmas(_, stopWords))
lemmatized.foreach(println)
```

I have taken it from the advanced analytics book on Spark, it seems like the stop words are not removed, and "is" is not converted to "be". Can we add or delete rules from these libraries?

http://www.textfixer.com/resources/common-english-words.txt